# reduce fields on paypal pay with credit card page

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

For payment I am redirecting the sender/customer from my site to Paypal site.On redirection sender can pay to merchant with Paypal account if he has Paypal account OR else with Credit/Debit Card.Now pay with credit card form has many fields,which the sender has to fill.So is there any way to reduce the fields by only keeping the credit card related information in that form.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal determines the fields that are used in the PayPal Hosted Page, however, if you are using PayPal standard you can have your customers fill out the form on your site and post the data to PayPal. Here are the [HTML Variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0J0VU) for filling out the PayPal form.
If you are not shipping an item and you do not require a shipping address, by setting the no_shipping variable [Shipping](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_BillingShippingAddress/#id08A9BM00A5Z) shipping will not be required and the PayPal Hosted page will not request a Shipping Address.

```
no_shipping = 1
```